# Docker with systemd-networkd

Tags: linux, dns, docker, systemd

I have a fresh install of Arch, using systemd-networkd as the network manager and systemd-resolved for DNS resolution. I am trying to run a number of containers, but none of them are able to access the internet/resolve domain names.

When I start an interactive shell from a container on the default bridge and `curl google.com`, I get `Failed to connect to google.com port 80: No route to host`.

I have already configured /etc/resolv.conf in stub mode, and created a .network file for my primary link, so I can access the internet from the host. I also enabled `IPForward=yes` as specified in the [Docker wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Docker#docker0_Bridge_gets_no_IP_/_no_internet_access_in_containers_when_using_systemd-networkd).

Does anyone know how to configure the docker network interfaces with networkd and resolved to give them DNS servers?

Output of ip addr:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp37s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:9c:23:1e:e9:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp38s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:91:e3:0d:c0:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.20/24 metric 1024 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic enp38s0
       valid_lft 2621sec preferred_lft 2621sec
    inet6 fe80::5291:e3ff:fe0d:c034/64 scope link proto kernel_ll
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:81:a0:ef:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
32: br-9e997675bb1b: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:b7:39:a1:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-9e997675bb1b
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:b7ff:fe39:a16e/64 scope link proto kernel_ll
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
34: veth51e882e@if33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 16:da:a8:84:7d:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::14da:a8ff:fe84:7da3/64 scope link proto kernel_ll
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of resolvectl:

```
Global
           Protocols: +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
    resolv.conf mode: stub
Fallback DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 8.8.8.8#dns.google
                      2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google

Link 2 (enp37s0)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (enp38s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1 205.171.2.65

Link 4 (docker0)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 32 (br-9e997675bb1b)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 34 (veth51e882e)
    Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

Output of networkctl:

```
IDX LINK            TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo              loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 enp37s0         ether    no-carrier  configuring
  3 enp38s0         ether    routable    configured
  4 docker0         bridge   no-carrier  unmanaged
 32 br-9e997675bb1b bridge   no-carrier  unmanaged
 34 veth51e882e     ether    degraded    configuring

6 links listed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is shown the output of networkctl; the last link (veth...) is 'degraded'. This is due to how I configured my .network file:

```
[Match]
Type=ether

[Network]
DHCP=yes
IPForward=yes
```

I matched based on type=ether because I have multiple ethernet NICs and wanted them all to be matched.

The issue with this is that some docker containers create virtual ethernet links which bind to the docker0 link. However, since they present themselves as ethernet type, networkd was trying to manage them, and they reached the 'degraded' state.

**The solution:** change the .network file to match based on name:

```
[Match]
Name=enp*

[Network]
DHCP=yes
IPForward=yes
```

After making this change and restarting networkd and dockerd, everything seems to be working, and this is the output of networkctl:

```
IDX LINK            TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo              loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 enp37s0         ether    no-carrier  configuring
  3 enp38s0         ether    routable    configured
  4 br-9e997675bb1b bridge   routable    unmanaged
  5 docker0         bridge   no-carrier  unmanaged
  9 br-99c39fddeeb0 bridge   routable    unmanaged
 11 vethc769b2b     ether    enslaved    unmanaged
 13 vethf160bb2     ether    enslaved    unmanaged

8 links listed.
```